# Cannot download the required library for mlkit

Tags: java, android, kotlin, firebase-mlkit

I'm using Firebase Vision for some text recognition. the problem is some devices can't download `libocr.so`. the app was working fine and there was no problem but now it cannot download the library. following is the stack trace of the error:

```
2019-10-17 18:23:45.516 30280-31305/com.scanner.scanner I/Vision: Request download for engine ocr is a no-op because rate limiting
2019-10-17 18:23:45.518 30280-31305/com.scanner.scanner I/Vision: Loading library libocr.so
2019-10-17 18:23:45.521 30280-31305/com.scanner.scanner I/Vision: libocr.so library load status: false
2019-10-17 18:23:45.521 30280-31305/com.scanner.scanner I/Vision: Request download for engine ocr is a no-op because rate limiting
2019-10-17 18:23:46.178 30280-31305/com.scanner.scanner V/DynamiteModule: Dynamite loader version >= 2, using loadModule2NoCrashUtils
2019-10-17 18:23:46.540 30280-31305/com.scanner.scanner W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.vision.ocr not found.
2019-10-17 18:23:46.540 30280-31305/com.scanner.scanner I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.vision.ocr:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.vision.ocr:0
2019-10-17 18:23:46.541 30280-31305/com.scanner.scanner E/Vision: Error loading module com.google.android.gms.vision.ocr optional module true: li: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
```

I tried cleaning Google Play services data and cache.

the problem isn't limited only to my app, I tried other apps from Google Play which using mlkit and they failed to download the library too.

Comment: Similar question: [Google Mobile Vision library not downloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42628627/google-mobile-vision-library-not-downloading)

Comment: @RicardoA. thanks for your comment. I have seen this question and even tested the app mentioned in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44334434/9428030 but it fails to download the library.

Comment: do you have the latest version of  Google Play Services installed?

Comment: @demo7up yes I do, it's 19.4.20

Comment: same problem occurred in firebase ml kit

Comment: Did you consider using a VPN? Some flutter tools are not available in some countries.

Comment: @AmirJ yes, I did. it seems like Google has blocked the device because of its policies. anyway, I used Tesseract.

Comment: @Kourosh did you rooted that device?

Comment: @AmirJ no, and I don't think that matters.